# Overriding in C++ in a hierarchy of classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In c++ in this hierarchy of classes

```
class n1
{
public:
    virtual void tt() { cout << "n1" << endl; }
};
class n2:public n1
{
public:
     void tt() { cout << "n2" << endl; }
};
class n3:public n2
{
    void tt() { cout << "n3" << endl; }
};
int main()
{
    n1 *k = new n3;
    k->tt();
}
```

In the third class is tt overriding n1 virtual function or it is simply hiding the n2 implementation?

In C# i get that you can override at any level in the hierarchy the virtual method from the lowest class..but i dont know if it is the same in C++.

```
Class a
{
    virtual void func();
};
class b : a
{
    override func()
};
class c : b
{
    override func()
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding it.

If you aren't sure whether your override is correct, we have a keyword called [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) (c++11 required), which makes sure your override fits the virtual function / method declaration.

This should clear things up:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class n1
{
public:
    virtual void tt() { cout << "n1" << endl; }
};

class n2:public n1
{
public:
    void tt() override { cout << "n2" << endl; }
};

class n3:public n2
{
    void tt() override { cout << "n3" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    n1 *a = new n1;
    n1 *b = new n2;
    n1 *c = new n3;

    a->tt();
    b->tt();
    c->tt();

    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
}
```

Outputs:
n1
n2
n3

[Live](http://ideone.com/cn2fGe)

> So in a 3 class hierarchy A->B->C if A has virtual method and B implements it ,it doesnt mean that classes derived from B will take the method already

If you do override it, then that override will be used.

[If you don't override the method, then the last overriden method will be used.](http://ideone.com/R817MU)

```
class n1
{
public:
    virtual void tt() { cout << "n1" << endl; }
};

class n2:public n1
{
public:
    void tt() override { cout << "n2" << endl; }
};

class n3:public n2
{

};
```

Outputs:
n1
n2
n2

Comment: So in a 3 class hierarchy  A->B->C if A has virtual method and B implements it ,it doesnt mean that classes derived from B will take the method already implemented.

Comment: @adrian.bercovici `B`'s version will be called *if* the method is called using virtual dispatch (or static dispatch to `B`). `A`'s version can still be called when using static dispatch, even on an instance of `B` ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/068cbcb577e090d0)). This is different from C#, where an inherited and overridden method effectively becomes private to the class that overrides it.